# How to set implementation of OncePerRequestFilter to filter only one endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Im using this Filter to log my requests and responses, it works very well, but I noticed that I didnt need actualy this filter for all my endpoints - it will be more efficient and enough to filtering and logging requests from only one endpoint.
Is it possible without making if statement in `afterRequest` method? 
Im searching this a lot, but almost every example is with spring security :(

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class RequestAndResponseLoggingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (isAsyncDispatch(request)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            doFilterWrapped(wrapRequest(request), wrapResponse(response), filterChain);
        }
    }

    protected void doFilterWrapped(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request, ContentCachingResponseWrapper response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        beforeRequest(request, response);
        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        finally {
            afterRequest(request, response);
            response.copyBodyToResponse();
        }
    }

    protected void beforeRequest(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request, ContentCachingResponseWrapper response) {
        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            val address = request.getRemoteAddr();
            val queryString = request.getQueryString();
            if (queryString == null) {
                log.info("{}> {} {}", address, request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI());
            } else {
                log.info("{}> {} {}?{}", address, request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(), queryString);
            }
            Collections.list(request.getHeaderNames()).forEach(headerName ->
                Collections.list(request.getHeaders(headerName)).forEach(headerValue ->
                    log.info("{}> {}: {}", address, headerName, headerValue)));
            val content = request.getContentAsByteArray();
            if (content.length > 0) {
                log.info("{}>", address);
                try {
                    val contentString = new String(content, request.getCharacterEncoding());
                    Stream.of(contentString.split("\r\n|\r|\n")).forEach(line -> log.info("{}> {}", address, line));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    log.info("{}> [{} bytes body]", address, content.length);
                }
            }
            log.info("{}>", address);
        }
    }

    protected void afterRequest(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request, ContentCachingResponseWrapper response) {
        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            val address = request.getRemoteAddr();
            val status = response.getStatus();
            log.info("{}< {} {}", address, status, HttpStatus.valueOf(status).getReasonPhrase());
            response.getHeaderNames().forEach(headerName ->
                response.getHeaders(headerName).forEach(headerValue ->
                    log.info("{}< {}: {}", address, headerName, headerValue)));
            val content = response.getContentAsByteArray();
            if (content.length > 0) {
                log.info("{}<", address);
                try {
                    val contentString = new String(content, request.getCharacterEncoding());
                    Stream.of(contentString.split("\r\n|\r|\n")).forEach(line -> log.info("{}< {}", address, line));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    log.info("{}< [{} bytes body]", address, content.length);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrapRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper) {
            return (ContentCachingRequestWrapper) request;
        } else {
            return new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        }
    }

    private static ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrapResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper) {
            return (ContentCachingResponseWrapper) response;
        } else {
            return new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i have understood your question. The shouldNotFilter will not execute this filter for paths matching the expression. 

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        return path.startsWith("/health");
    }